# java apache configuration: special characters ";" and "#" in value

Tags: java, apache, configuration, special-characters

I use for my configuration file org.apache.commons.configuration.Configuration.
Now I have the following key-value-pair:

```
mySpecialKey = ABC,;#XYZ
```

I need for this one value the 3 special characters ",", ";" and "#". 
But ";" and "#" have in my other key-value-pairs the original comment function.
I can mask "," with "\", but I haven't a solution to mask ";" and "#".
How can I resolve my problem? Thanks for your hints, Stefanie

Comment: Yes, this is the solution. Alexander thanks, Stefanie

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the RHS in quotes? Like: `"ABC,;#XYZ"`